# I am writing a VBA code but getting Compile Error: Expected: expression

Tags: excel, vba

My code Please check where the issue is. I am getting Compile Error: Expected: expression:-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblCol As Range
    
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DATATABLE") 
    Set tblCol = tbl.ListColumns("Value Date(dd/mm/yyy)").DataBodyRange
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, tblCol)
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            If Not IsDate(Target.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a valid date in DD/MM/YYYY format."
                Target.Value = ""
            Else
                If Len(Target.Value) <> 10 Then
                    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date in DD/MM/YYYY format."
                    Target.Value = ""
                Else
                    If Mid(Target.Value, 3, 2) > 12 Or Left(Target.Value, 2) > 31 Then
                        MsgBox "Please enter a valid date in DD/MM/YYYY format."
                        Target.Value = ""
                    Else
                        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(tblCol) > 0 Then
                            MsgBox "Please enter a date in all cells of the column."
                            Target.Value = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(tblCol) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a date in all cells of the column."
                Target.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Image of the issue. Please check image to understand the issue [image]

Comment: On which line did you get the error? Can you give me details about it?

Comment: Compiles for me.

Comment: I am running on Excel it is throwing me this without telling me any line number

Comment: As this code compiles without problems (and if not, VBA would show you the exact line): Do you have AddIns or do you reference any other Excel files? What happens if you remove the code except for the Sub and End Sub statement?

Comment: If all the text is red like it shows in your image , one may assume there are a bunch of illegal characters in the code, try to remove all the spaces in the code, you may have to do it line by line until each line turns black

Comment: ...or since it compiles fine when  copy/pasted from your post, do that.